# Sharing Groups between site collections/web applications

Tags: 2013, search, permissions, site-collection, web-application

I am currently setting up an enterprise search centre and have run into the problem of users from the intranet not having access permission. I was wondering if there is a way to copy/share across the SharePoint groups to the new site collection/web application or am I stuck re-assigning everybody's permissions again from AD?

And If I have to reassign permissions do their permissions on the intranet auto cull things they don't have access to when the search centre returns its results or are the search results based on the search centre permissions?

Comment: If you are going to give everyone access to the Search center, then follow Microsofts instructions for doing so. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582314.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box it's not possible to copy permissions between site collections. You can copy permissions programmatically, as explained in [How To Copy Permissions Between Site Collections](http://mosswat.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-copy-permissions-between-site.html)

However, it's considered a best practice to make a security group in Active Directory and add that security group to each of the site collections. Then all you need to do is assigning the group with same permission level.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8138.sharepoint-2010-copying-permissions-between-site-collections.aspx

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought that would be the way I would have to go